# Join 2 subnets on Raspberry Pi

Tags: networking, routing, vpn, subnets

I have setup a small Wireguard VPN network between 3 devices:

- Digital Ocean VPS (server, 10.222.0.1)
- Raspberry Pi on my home network (peer, 10.222.0.2)
- iPhone 11 (peer, 10.222.0.3)

From any device, I can ping the others. The VPN is functional. What I want now is for the iPhone (which is outside of my home network) to see an IP camera on my home network which has an IP address of 192.168.1.64. This is beyond my capabilities to do alone so I was looking for some assistance.

Ultimately, I need the iPhone which his entering the Pi to be connected/routed from the 10.222.0.x subnet to the 192.168.1.x subnet.

Would appreciate an suggestions, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Edited following the comment]

The very first thing to do when networking is to draw a picture, coordinated for **segments**:

```
10.222.0.*/24                          192.168.1.*/24                 ISP
      |                                     |                          |
      |                                     +-- 192.168.1.1   Router --+
      |                                     |
      +-- 10.222.0.2  RaspPi  192.168.1.? --+
      |                                     |
      +-- 10.222.0.1  D.O.VPS               +-- 192.168.1.64  Camera
      |                                     |
      +-- 10.222.0.3  iPhone 11             |
      |                                     |
```

The next question you need to answer is "who sets up the default gateway address in each LAN segement, and which one is it?".

If this is the RaspPi for both segments, the answer is easy: enable forwarding on the RaspPi, done.

If it's not the RaspPi, please edit your question and include this information (potentially your home router for your home network?). In this case, you either need to set up **routes** on the default gateway (which may or may not be possible on your home router), or set static routes on each member of the segment, or distribute routes via DHCP.

The basic principle is: On a chain from a source to a destination (and back), each single computer needs to know where to route a packet next. It's a network design exercise, not something you can only do on the RaspPi.

---

So your router is the default gateway for `192.168.1.*/24`, and also runs DHCP for this segment. There's a no DHCP for `10.222.0.*/24` (static addresses), and no default gateway.

So one possible solution is to set up the RaspPi as default gateway for `10.222.0.*/24`. You can do that statically, just like the IP addresses, details depend on the OS. For example [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html#%5BNetwork%5D%20Section%20Options) is how to do it with systemd. Verify with `ip route`.

Next investigate if you can set routes on your Unify router. You need a route to `10.222.0.0/24` (if it is a `/24`, that was a guess) via the RaspPi address, and the RaspPi needs to get always the same address in `192.168.1.*/24` (that's something you can configure on most routers).

Finally, make sure forwarding is enabled on the RaspPi. You can check this with

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

(1 is enabled), or set this manually with

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

If it's not enabled by default, the ways to make this permanent again depend on the OS.

Comment: Thanks again for explaining and for updating your response. I have been reading this over and over but I just can't grasp it. The only thing I am sure of is that the RaspPi has a static ip of 192.168.1.150 on the lan, and 10.222.0.2 on the Wireguard network. I can't work out how to make the pi a gateway, do I do it on the pi itself, or on the Wireguard server settings? After all I don't want the pi to be a gateway for 192.168.1.x, only for the 10.222.0.x range. In fact, if it makes like easier, I can change the Wireguard subnet/ip range to anything.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that the iPhone doesn't know where it can find the `192.168.1.*` network. (also written as `192.168.1.0/24` where the `0`specifies the whole network and the `/24` the netmask)

In you Wireguard configuration on the iPhone you should have a `AllowedIPs` line. This line configures the available routes over the VPN to the iPhone. So if this says `AllowedIPs=10.222.0.0/24` the only allowed IP's over the VPN are the `10.222.0.0/24` subnet.
You would like to extend that to also allow you LAN network to go over the VPN by updating the line as follow: `AllowedIPs=10.222.0.0/24,192.168.1.0/24`

If the line says `AllowedIPs=0.0.0.0/0` then it means that it will pass all of the traffic (including internet traffic) over the VPN.

In addition to that: Like the previous post describes, the raspberry pi should allow routing.
This can be checked by the following command `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` if it returns a 1 routing is enabled.

To permanently enable routing to the Pi you should uncomment `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`

Apply the change with `sysctl -p`

Assuming there is no firewall running on the Pi you should now be able to access the camera.